# Making APK for flutter project on VSCode windows

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apk, embedding

I am working on a project and while converting it to an APK file, I am facing an error:

```
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

  C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter_project_buddy_new\new_buddy_code\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?
The detected reason was:

  C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter_project_buddy_new\new_buddy_code\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?�?

Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.1.5+1\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.    
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-7.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] 
Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.5.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\aayus\Documents\flutter_project_buddy_new\new_buddy_code\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          195.9s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (19.2MB).
```

Even though the APK file is generated, it is a blank file.
I work on a Windows 10 device
Rest of the things are in order and flutter doctor runs with no issues
Can anyone help out here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (19.2MB).` 19,2MB of "blank file" ?

Comment: How can it be a blank file? The size is 19.2MB which seems completely fine. Please go to the correct location and check the file again.

Comment: Blank as in a white screen and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:name="${applicationName}"` in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. the weird thing seems like there is misspelt

'/Users/builder/clone/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication'

I try to search FutterApplication on my AndroidManifest.xml but could not found

Comment: Do you happen to fix the issue?